# Is there a name for misusing a word (e.g., saying "Provincially, yes")?

Tags: meaning-in-context, terminology, adverbs, sentence, errors

I read a mail in which someone replied to the question "Will he be attending the party?" by saying "Provincially, yes".

[*Provincial*](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/provincial) means "of or concerning the regions outside the capital city of a country, especially when regarded as unsophisticated or narrow-minded", but neither the natural nor the pejorative meaning seems to fit here.

What was meant? And is there a name for abusing the language in this way?

Comment: I voted to close as too localized: “This question is unlikely to help any future visitors; it is only relevant to a small geographic area, a specific moment in time, or an extraordinarily narrow situation that is not generally applicable to the worldwide audience of the internet. For help making this question more broadly applicable, see the FAQ.”

Comment: I've attempted to make the question less localised. Please join in if it can be further improved.

Comment: Since I believe the example can be explained that the person answering the question, "Will he be attending the party?" meant to say ***"provisionally, yes"***, there is merit in re-opening this question and allowing the OP to get an answer on what this misuse of words is called.

Comment: ['catachresis'](https://www.google.com/search?q=catachresis+definition&aq=f&oq=catachresis+definition) is the literary term for this misuse of words.

Comment: See also https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/380454/need-softer-less-potentially-offensive-word-for-malapropism https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/229802/term-for-the-blatant-use-of-the-wrong-word https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/562262/is-there-a-term-for-unconsciously-using-a-wrong-word-when-speaking-because-you-w etc

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's a [malapropism](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/malapropism?q=malapropism) and should read *Provisionally*, "subject to further confirmation, for the time being."

Comment: "Provisionally, 'yes', and provincially, 'aye'". ;)

Comment: Or if they were feeling blessed that they were attending, perhaps the intent was *providentially*.